# What logic can I use in SQL where I am getting two results which are both correct, but I need to pick just one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a novice programmer and I am also learning to ask right questions and become a better writer so do comment some tips if you notice anything wrong with the way I asked my question or explained.  Here we go:

I have a request from a user, who wants me to write a code, which gets the term for which the applicants who applied for a specific program of study (example:"Information Systems") was accepted.

I am not sure if this is bad data or what exactly happened, but while QC'ing the user came across a student who applied for a specific program of study twice (in Summer 2011 and Summer 2012) and was accepted both times.  When the user QC'd, for some reason, Summer 2011 was showing in front-end.  The user has requested that I show the latest term only for that program of study.  I can't find any flags or alternatives to narrow my search.

Does anyone know what I can do (what logic can I use) to choose the latest term.  The table does has lastchangedate column, but I'm not sure if I can use it since students can apply to 20 different program of studies.

More information:

I will be putting my code into a existing stored procedure. Also, I will be inserting this term information in a table.

here's what my code looks like logic wise:

```
DECLARE @MiscID int......

SELECT @MiscID = sys_miscinfotablesdetailsid from sys_miscinfotablesdetails 
where      attributename = 'Start Term for Billing'....

INSERT INTO sss_studentstudyprogramsmisc
(  
AttributeValue.......
)

SELECT 

T.Name [AttributeValue],....

FROM

SMS_StudentsInstance i
inner join.....(blah blah)

where WHERE sspm.AttributeValue IS NULL
```

Please do let me know if I need to provide more information.  I would appreciate this. I asked the Sr. Engineer on my team and he told me: "do some datetime comparison to term date times. I have no idea how you'd pull it off for a current summer term. good luck :)".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY` to order by the term the student applied using the `DESC` keyword for descending order, then you can limit the number of records using `TOP 1`. There are plenty of examples for both on the web to look at.

Comment: This would work in MySQL, but not SQL Server (SQL Server doesn't have the LIMIT clause)

Comment: SQL Server would use "top 1"

Answer (score 1):

See the below query. By using a common table expression you can add a `row_number()` column to the source table, and use that column to specify that you only want the first.

```
create table #t ( id int, string nvarchar(10))

insert into #t values (1, '1')
insert into #t values (1, '1')
insert into #t values (2, '2')
insert into #t values (3, '3')
insert into #t values (4, '4')

create table #newt ( id int, string nvarchar(10))

;with oldt as 
(
   select id, string, 
   rnum = row_number() over(partition by id, string order by id, string) 
   from #t
)
insert into #newt
select id, string
from oldt where rnum = 1
```

ETA: The trick is that the `partition by` should contain all fields defining uniqueness. The `order by` is required but doesn't really matter in this case. BUT if you had a primary key field or a change/version date field you could use that for the most recent: `order by primaryId desc`.

ETA2: Here is a generalization of how it would be applied to your SP:

```
DECLARE @MiscID int......

SELECT @MiscID = sys_miscinfotablesdetailsid from sys_miscinfotablesdetails 
where      attributename = 'Start Term for Billing'....

-- Wrap existing select in a CTE.
-- CTE needs to start with a semicolon
-- and needs to be placed above the INSERT
;WITH cte AS (

  SELECT 

  T.Name [AttributeValue],....
     -- Add the row_number function column
     -- Include all fields you are selecting in the partition by
     -- Find appropriate order by 
     rnum = row_number() over(partition by t.Name, ... order by lastchangedate desc)
  FROM

  SMS_StudentsInstance i
  inner join.....(blah blah)

  WHERE sspm.AttributeValue IS NULL 
)
INSERT INTO sss_studentstudyprogramsmisc
(  
AttributeValue.......
)
-- Simple select from the CTE instead 
SELECT AttributeValue, ...
FROM cte
-- ...but only for the first record
WHERE rnum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Malk!  I will definitely try this out.  I did think may be I could use CTE but wasn't sure if I can use parameters that uses other tables to get values with CTE.